# Python SQLAlchemy commit to two different dbs one MSSQL and other PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql-server, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to commit to two different dbs, one hosted on MSSQL and the other PostgreSQL. I have two different session objects. I know I can do the following,

```
session1.add(record) // MSSQL session
session1.commit() 
session2.add(record) // PostgreSQL session
session2.commit()
```

But, I am trying keep then in sync, so either both successful or both fail (if one of them fails don't commit to other). I would appreciate any help or thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the distributed transaction coordinator to create a [distributed transaction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177403(v=sql.105).aspx).

There is an old saying: A man who has one watch knows what time it is, a man who has two is never sure.